# Convolution of Histograms inside cell array

Tags: matlab

Hello I need to use convolution between histograms that are in a cell array named H (and each histogram is a cell array itself).

```
   for i=1:16
    H_curr = conv(H_curr,H(i));
   end                    PS : H_curr and H(i) are already initialized with a histogram.
```

For example histogram 1 is [73,167,13].

It doesn't work since "First and second arguments must be numeric or logical."

I tried to convert the histograms to vectors (with cell2mat) but it didn't work..

```
 H_curr = conv(cell2mat(H_curr),cell2mat(H(i)));
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :

cell2mat() worked but the H_curr was already a double vector since it is the output of hist() so the error was because I tried to do cell2mat() to something that wasn't a cell.